# How to draw single axis plot in R

Tags: r, graph

I wish to draw very very simple line with three numbers. It would be like below

```
|------|--------------| 
0.5   1.5           3.4
```

Is it too simple to ask?

Answer (score 4):

First, `plot` nothing, remove the axes, and add an x-axis back in at the specified points:

```
x <- c(.5, 1.5, 3.4)
plot(0, xlim = c(0, 3.5), axes=FALSE, type = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "")
axis(1, at = x, labels = x)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks A lot! Yes, it is simple, but it is very worthy for me!

Answer (score 1):

```
plot(1:10, rep(0,10), type='b', pch='|', axes=F, xlab="", ylab="", xlim=c(0,10))
text(1:10, rep(-0.1,10), labels=1:10)
```

margins and plot size can be tweaked with `X11` and `par`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in grid,

```
library(grid)
grid.newpage()
grid.xaxis(at=c(0.5, 1.5, 3.4), 
           vp=vpStack(viewport(height=unit(2,"lines")),
                      viewport(y=1, xscale = c(0.4, 3.5), just="bottom")))
```

[image]